# Huawei Unity IAP Kit integration getting error code -1, error code 6004

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated Huawei IAP kit in unity and I have checked in sandbox testing, the payment is not getting failed and showing **INVALID REQUEST**.

I checked the logs and **Huawei IAP showing error as -1**. Also getting below log

```
17:26684 SourceFile:723] checkPermission, appID:*********, permission:com.huawei.android.hms.game.base, accountIndex:null, checkexpiredTimeFlag:1
17:26684 SourceFile:731] permission not exist
ce 20017:26684 SourceFile:457] Failed to check the permission, appID: *********, errorCode: 6004, permission: com.huawei.android.hms.game.base, checkExpiredTimeFlag: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your logs it seems CP have not applied required permissions from AGC.

**6004** : API authentication: **Permission not granted** from HUAWEI Developers

For details , please refer below official link:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/error-code-0000001050045846

Below are the common preconditions in HMS which must be enabled from AGC to use this service:

1. Huawei Account activated
2. Merchant Account activated
3. In App purchasing API enabled
4. Once enabled above services ---->Add Products to AppGallery Connect.